# Mysql query error on insert

Tags: mysql, magento2.1

I am using the following query to insert bidding info but it throws an Cardinality violation error.

Error thrown as follows

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row, query was: INSERT INTO `auction_bidders` (`property_id`, `customer_id`, `total_bid_amount`, `bid_amount`, `bid_placed_time`, `title_service_charge`, `is_bid_withdrawn`, `is_proxy`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '2018-01-13 16:53:32', ?, ?, ?)
```

Code i used as follows

```
public function placeAuctionBid($property_id, $customer_id, $bid_amount){
        $bidder_data = array(
            'property_id' => $property_id,
            'customer_id' => $customer_id,
            'total_bid_amount' => $bid_amount,
            'bid_amount' => $bid_amount,
            'bid_placed_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'title_service_charge' => 0,
            'is_bid_withdrawn' => 0,
            'is_proxy'=>1
        );
        $this->biddersModel->setData($bidder_data);
        $this->biddersModel->save();
        $this->initiateBiddingWar();
        return true;
    }
```

Its a magento 2.1 code

Any ideas?

Comment: The insert statement in the error message should not be generating this error AFAIK.  Can you include the original code which generated this error?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated my question

Comment: I don't see a sub-query in the insert statement. Could it be possible that a trigger / stored procedure is being invoked which is resulting in this error?